# A strange behavior about the console.log in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console.log, eventemitter

I am learning EventEmitter. 
and I have a simple stupid test. (node --version v8.4.0 on win10)

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const emiter1 = new EventEmitter()
const emiter2 = new EventEmitter()

// let cnt = 1

emiter1.on('ping', () => {
    // console.log('ping' + cnt++)
    emiter2.emit('pong')
})

emiter2.on('pong', () => {
    // console.log('pong' + cnt++)
    emiter1.emit('ping')
})

emiter1.emit('ping')
```

I expect it will become a infinity function call, because `emit()` is a sync function.

Here is the output.:

```
$ node em.js
C:\tmp\em.js:13
    emiter2.on('pong', () => {
                    ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at EventEmitter.emiter2.on (C:\electron-workspace\tmp\em.js:13:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at EventEmitter.emiter1.on (C:\electron-workspace\tmp\em.js:10:17)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at EventEmitter.emiter2.on (C:\electron-workspace\tmp\em.js:15:17)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at EventEmitter.emiter1.on (C:\electron-workspace\tmp\em.js:10:17)
```

Great! Just as I expected.
But after I uncomment the `cnt` and `console.log`, I got a strange behavior. 
The program finished without an error, and stop at `cnt==1600` (sometime is 1598, 1599)

```
$ node em.js
ping1
pong2
ping3
pong4
...
...
pong1596
ping1597
pong1598
ping1599
pong1600

$
```

I run `node em.js 1> out.txt 2> err.txt` and both `console.log` and `console.err` are correct just as I expect. But I'm still wondering why the err didn't print out directly in my shell?
Is there a reasonable explanation? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a ton of output being logged in one tick like this (since event emitters run event callbacks synchronously), it's likely that the stack trace just didn't have time to buffer to the console before Node exited.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate, but I'd guess stdout will keep printing `cnt` until the maximum call stack is reached at which point the program will terminate, the buffer may/may not contain the stack trace.  I ran here https://repl.it/repls/FearlessDistortedYellowjacket and still got the trace on some runs.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I run `node em.js 1> out.txt 2> err.txt` and both `console.log` and `console.err` are correct just as I expect.
But I'm still wondering why the err didn't print out directly in my shell?

Comment: I got it. Thanks for node community.
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18232

Comment: Writes(console.log, console.err) may be synchronous depending on what the stream is connected to and whether the system is Windows or POSIX. see
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o
 and https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_printing_in_asynchooks_callbacks